# Dapper's execute method returns two different results for insert and delete

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

When i use the ***Execute*** method of Dapper for a **INSERT** stored procedure, if query works successfully, it returns **1** as expected , but when i use it for a **DELETE** stored procedure, it returns **-1** even query works successfully. In this case, success for **DELETE** stored procedure is "-1"?

```
 public override int Insert(Language entity)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("Id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            parameters.Add("Name", entity.Name, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("Culture", entity.Culture, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("Published", entity.Published, DbType.Boolean);
            parameters.Add("DisplayOrder", entity.DisplayOrder, DbType.Int32);
            int numberOfRowsAffected = Connection.Execute("Language_Insert", 
                parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            // numberOfRowsAffected = 1
            return parameters.Get<int>("Id");
        }

 public override bool Delete(int primaryKey)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("Id", primaryKey, DbType.Int32);
            int numberOfRowsAffected = Connection.Execute("Language_Delete",
                parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            // numberOfRowsAffected = -1
            return numberOfRowsAffected > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper can't see inside your stored procedure; anything that is different in these two cases is specific to the internals of the two commands. Ultimately, dapper is just returning the value from `ExecuteCommand`.

There are a few things that could cause the difference:

- `SET NOCOUNT ON`
- the presence of a `TRIGGER` (including `CASCADE`, `SET NULL` etc constraint / foreign key clauses)
- additional operations after the `INSERT`/`DELETE`

If you want reliable values from this type of operation,you should use an `OUTPUT` or `RETURN` parameter instead, set via `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: You are absolutely right sir. It was because of "Set miscount on", thank u very much:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try structuring your code like this.

```
public override bool Delete(int primaryKey)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("Id", primaryKey, DbType.Int32);
        parameters.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        parameters.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        Connection.Execute("Language_Delete",
            parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        int b = parameters.Get<int>("@b");
        // Output
        int c = parameters.Get<int>("@c");
        // ReturnValue



    }
```